# Syntax error on token "if", invalid AnnotationName

Tags: java, android

Hi I am working with android and I'm trying to put an "if" statement around this class but I get the error "Syntax error on token "if", invalid AnnotationName" 
Any help?

```
    private String str = "0"; 
if(str == 0){
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
     {

         //Handle the back button
         if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
         {
             //Ask the user if they want to quit
             new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
             .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
             .setTitle("Coupon")
             .setMessage("Do you want a coupon texted to you?")
             .setPositiveButton("YES!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                 {
                     //Stop the activity
                     Toast.makeText(buttonOne.this, "Great! You'll get one in just a couple of minutes.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                     finish();
                 }
             })
             .setNegativeButton("Not now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                 {
                     //Stop the activity
                     finish();
                 }
             })
             .show();        
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
         }

     }
}
else
{}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't put control structures (like `if` statements) outside a function.

Answer (score 1):

you must use `equals` String method:

```
if (str.equals("0")){
    ...
}
```